# How to extend Array to enforce specific arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, static-analysis, es6-class

I'm using TypeScript and I want to extend `Array` to enforce a specific argument.  This way, I can make sure that whenever I create a FruitArray, the first element is a fruit.

So I tried extending `Array` in a class:

```
class FruitArray extends Array {
  constructor(fruit: FruitsEnum, ...args: string[]) {
    if (!enumContains(FruitsEnum, fruit)) {
      throw new Error('Must initialize with a fruit!');
    }
    super(fruit, ...args);
  }
}
```

However, the linter complains:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest
> parameter.

I think I am handling `super()` wrong, but I don't understand how to get it to work.

Comment: why is `args` string? Isn't it need to be FruitsEnum ?

Comment: Typescripts static types are 100% erased at runtime. Therefore, your desire to subclass javascript's array because you want to enforce an element type past to an erased type should be rethought, and this is compounded 100% by the fact that the element type is based on a compile time enum construct which doesn't even result in elements that aren't strings or numbers. Please reconsider your approach to typescript. This is not Java or C#, it's not python or PHP, it is pure JavaScript checked for Mistakes by typescript at compile time. Nothing more. You can't be good in TS unless you're good in JS

Comment: @AluanHaddad That is a good point, but as you can see in the code snippet I posted, I am throwing an error if the enum object is invalid, so it is clearly not "just at compile time" in this case.

Comment: That's a good point which I overlooked. However, I would argue a factory function would be appropriate and also offer stronger typing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll address the problem you asked about, but then point out a couple of things that may bite you with the approach of extending `Array`.

Re the specific error, it looks like the problem is that you've extended `Array` without specifying its element type. With the error ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM4FFzQN4CgoFQCCACiQDLpQC8UAREQA6MA2wdANPoQEJEByAojXo8AhiAljOuAL65cAYxZjUqWAhRE4cMQE8owAB7JQAE3XbdBvISiKA9iFTIEi5A7gAKAGabkAFwaSGiYkBxQAHTRcMAuQS5wiCAA5gDaALoAlFC2doSOzg5skSwOKV4ABoWJYO6eQQAk2H4hspVZANzc+VAA9H1QiD5QXgCEoJAAwk7IYsmoXvAhGFgRrShZOXm9A-nIABZwDgDuUCDAZ+g6nl50ALJgLkMgKIhiLIgAXsBQJygHKBiKAbZBjOhdHr5PbyXoEVBgRjAbygiLRSKxFyQuzyeRAA)):

```typescript
class FruitArray extends Array {
    //                        ^−−−−−− no type parameter here
    // ...
}
```

Specifying an element type makes the error go away, for example here I'm giving `FruitsEnum | string` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM4FFzQN4CgoFQCCACiQDLpQC8UAREQA6MA2wdANPoQEJEByAojXo8AhiAljOuAL65cAYxZjUqWAhRE4cMQE8owAB7JQAE3XbdegDzwkaTJCgAfKKmRxEIAOYA+KDxCKEUAexAPBEVkULgACgAzTWQALg0HDCwOKAA6PLhgDzTI7x8AbQBdAEpA7mCCMIjQthyWUJ84gANGyLBo2LSAEmwkh1lOqoBuOvqAelmoRASoOIBCUEgAYXDkMW9UOPsUTMhs0ZQqmqD6gnn65AALOFCAdygQYDf0HVi4ugBZMAeRYgFCIMQsRAAL2AUBeKAeUDEUHOyFWdCmM2Cd3kNwIqDAjGA8VR2TyOQKHkxwXk8iAA)):

```typescript
class FruitArray extends Array<FruitsEnum | string> {
    // ...
}
```

---

Separately, though, a couple of issues with extending `Array` like this:

1. Your code isn't handling all of the construction signatures it has to handle to properly subclass `Array`. It needs to support at least these:

   - A single argument that's a number = create an empty array with the given length
   - A single argument that isn't a number = create an array with that one value as an element
   - Multiple arguments = create an array with those elements

   (I don't *think* it needs to support zero arguments. In the JavaScript specification, when creating arrays it does so via [`ArrayCreate`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arraycreate) and [`ArraySpeciesCreate`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrayspeciescreate), both of which expect a `length` argument. But double-check me before relying on that.)

   TypeScript doesn't complain about not handling that first argument being a number (because overlaying types on JavaScript's `Array` after the fact is *hard*), but your `fruit` parameter's value may well be a number. [Example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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):

   ```typescript
   const f = new FruitArray(FruitsEnum.APPLE, "x");
   const f2 = f.slice(1); // <== Calls your constructor with 1 as the only argument
   ```
2. While you can ensure that `FruitArray` *starts out* with a `FruitsEnum` value as its first element, that can soon become untrue ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM4FFzQN4CgoFQCCACiQDLpQC8UAREQA6MA2wdANPoQEJEByAojXo8AhiAljOuAL65cAYxZjUqWAhRE4cMQE8owAB7JQAE3XbdegDzwkaTJCgAfKKmRxEIAOYA+KDxCKEUAexAPBEVkULgACgAzTWQALg0HDCwOKAA6PLhgDzTI7x8AbQBdAEpA7mCCMIjQthyWUJ84gANGyLBo2LSAEmwkh1lOqoBuOvqAelmoRASoOIBCUEgAYXDkMW9UOPsUTMhs0ZQqmqD6gnn65AALOFCAdygQYDf0HVi4ugBZMAeRYgFCIMQsRAAL2AUBeKAeUDEUHOyFWdCmM2Cd3kNwIqDAjGA8VR2TyOQKHkxwXk8iU4WBy1oHzeR2QVn0h2SJwgOVIFHQ2ToRgx0wSZQADBURMK6NMes1gK12nEAFIAZQA8vwciVfEs9IlLtM7nizeaAHoAflwQA)):

   ```typescript
   const f = new FruitArray(FruitsEnum.APPLE, "x");
   f[0] = "x";
   console.log(JSON.stringify(f));
   //                         ^? const f: FruitArray
   ```

   There, `f` is still a `FruitArray`, but the first element is now a string, not a `FruitsEnum`.

You may be better off defining a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) or your own class that doesn't directly extend `Array` (it could use an array in its implementation), but it depends on what you're going to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to extend Array? can't you use something like this?

```
const fruitArray = new Array<FruitsEnum>()
```

**for the class implementation:**

Why does fruits array have 2 types? `string` and `FruitsEnum`? Why dont you just use FruitsEnum If you are going to enforce FruitsEnum type?

```js
enum FruitsEnum {

}

class FruitArray extends Array<FruitsEnum> {
  constructor(fruit: FruitsEnum, ...args: FruitsEnum[]) {
    ...
    super(fruit, ...args);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but only the first argument will be `FruitsEnum`; any additional arguments will be regular strings.